# Azure web apps: how do you achieve high availability?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

With iaas VMs you utilize availability groups but I'm missing how you achieve high availability (redundancy of all tiers cross fault/update domains) when using a web app. Do you need to manually add at least two instances to the app service plan?

Comment: Do you check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/managed-web-app/multi-region-web-app)?